Default Date Format displaying on Exposed Filter
In a multi shared Core/Theme D7 environment - setting up a Exposed Filter in a View using a Date Field formatted to use a custom date type to show m/d/Y...on one site it shows in exposed filter the correct date format is showing but the other site shows the date format as l, F j, Y.  Popup Date module is enabled. Checked Regional Settings, Date and Time - exported the view on both sites and can't figure out how that date format works in exposed filters.  I'd like the users to enter when filtering a simple date like 07/09/2024 rather than Wednesday, July 09, 2024.  There is also no Format option when editing the exposed filter...it's bugging me where to go to make the change the date format to show m/d/Y. Does anyone know where to make this change?

Do these date formats have names? Is it to do with the given site's configured date formats as seen at /admin/config/regional/date-time?

This question is similar to: How do i change date format in View Exposed Date filter?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes I saw that response and it's not the same question...unfortunately I don't have access to create a custom module or make back-end changes...200+ sites sharing the same code base...security is tight as a result.  It's just odd that two sites same core/theme/modules diff db, has the exposed date format showing differently.  At https://drupalize.me/tutorial/create-view-exposed-date-filters for ex. around 13 minutes shows what I mean...in this case it shows even a different format of the date E.g. 2012-04-10

I figured it out...still doesn't make sense but it's working now...I renamed my Date type created for the View and once I did that and adjusted the Date field in the View to use the same Date type with a different name ...it's working now.  Thanks for the quick reply on my first question...yay.
